# VLang Language Server for LSP-Zero.nvim

Tags: neovim, liskov-substitution-principle, vlang

I'm trying to setup the VLS ( V Language Server ) on nvim using [LSP-Zero](https://github.com/VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim), I just don't know how to setup the server. This is my current configuration:

lsp.lua:

```lua
local lsp_configurations = require('lspconfig.configs')

if not lsp_configurations.my_new_lsp then
  lsp_configurations.vlang_lsp = {
    default_config = {
      name = 'vlang_lsp',
      cmd = {'vlang_lsp'},
      filetypes = {'vlang'},
      root_dir = require('lspconfig.util').root_pattern('C:/Users/filip/.vls/bin'),
    }
  }
end

require('lspconfig').vlang_lsp.setup({})
```

init.lua:

```lua
vim.cmd([[au BufNewFile,BufRead *.v set filetype=vlang]])
```